# Extract terrain coordinates as seen from a viewpoint + FoV in a digital globe

Tags: cesium, terrain, tin, photogrammetry, maxar-digitalglobe

#### Context

Every one working with photogrammetry or 3D knows what a depth image is. For example [OpenCV](https://opencv.org) defines a "depth map" from a stereo pair, e.g.:

[image: depth map from stereo pair of images]

where the darker a pixel is, the greater the distance to the camera center.

#### Needs

I need to go a step further.

Let's say I have a triangulated DEM in a digital globe (in my particular case it's a [terrain mesh](https://github.com/CesiumGS/quantized-mesh) rendered in [CesiumJS](https://cesium.com/cesiumjs/) but I also have the corresponding DEM as a [GeoTIFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoTIFF)).

I need to figure out a mean to extract the terrain WGS84 coordinates as it is seen from a simulated camera at a given point of view. This point if view is defined as follows with known values for:

- the position,
- the 3D orientation,
- the focal length,
- the image size (width, height and corresponding numbers of pixels, (x,y))

All these values define the 3D cone of visibility, a.k.a. [field of view](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_view).

As an example, the frame of such an image is depicted here in green (this rectangular shape can be given as a GeoJSON, KML or whatever format in terrain space):

[image: Cesium screenshot with frame of the image]

This Cesium screenshot example simply corresponds to a [Viewer](https://cesium.com/docs/cesiumjs-ref-doc/Viewer.html) with a base [imageryProvider](https://cesium.com/docs/cesiumjs-ref-doc/ImageryProvider.html) and a [terrainProvider](https://cesium.com/docs/cesiumjs-ref-doc/TerrainProvider.html):

```js
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
    imageryProvider : new Cesium.BingMapsImageryProvider({
        url : 'https://dev.virtualearth.net',
        key : `${BING_MAP_TOKEN}`,
        mapStyle : Cesium.BingMapsStyle.AERIAL
    }),

    terrainProvider: new Cesium.CesiumTerrainProvider({
        url : `https://api.maptiler.com/tiles/terrain-quantized-mesh/?key=${MAPTILER_APP_TOKEN}`
    }),
    baseLayerPicker : false,
    infoBox : false,
});
```

[RGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model) values from terrain should be mapped as R=longitude, G=latitude, B=ellipsoidal height.

All these 3 values corresponds to the terrain coordinates for each defined pixel of the image.

Any 2D tool with some kind of [viewshed analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewshed_analysis) where one can define a picture frame and its internal parameters are also welcome, but here, I preferred to represent the story using real 3D.

Any hints are welcome.
I'm working on a full open source stack (Ubuntu + GIS tools).